# How to create custom softkeys

Tags: qt, symbian

I would like to create an application similar to the screenshot, using the Qt Widgets framework (not QML like on the screenshot).

Unfortunately I am unable to remove the default CBA area. If I enter full-screen mode with

```
QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_S60DontConstructApplicationPanes);
```

the status area on the top is also removed which is not what I need.

[image]

Comment: What does your application look right now? Could you post a screenshot for comparison

Comment: Here is the current state of the app: http://i50.tinypic.com/5aib6b.jpg , as you can see my right softkey is not visible and that's why I want to have custom softkeys.